# Ordering results by multiple values of same column

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gets contacts from a database based on their title. It looks for multiple titles and if multiple contacts get returned from the same query, I'd like them to come in a specific order. Here's what I mean:

This is an example of the table:

```
id   | name      | title              | email
-----+-----------+--------------------+------------------
1    | Bob       | General Manager    | bob@example.com
2    | John      | President          | john@example.com
3    | Sue       | Owner              | sue@example.com
```

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE title IN ('General Manager', 'Owner', 'President')
```

How can I made the query return the results in a specific order (or hierarchy of titles in my case)?

I'd like the results of always being in the order:

1. General Manager
2. Owner
3. President

If there is no general manager for that entity, for example, I'd like to still keep the same hierarchy and return:

1. Owner
2. President

Comment: Outside of your normal asc/desc ORDER BY functionality, there is not a way to do this that I know of. Your DB design should include a Display Order column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use [`FIELD`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php) function. It returns position of the search string in the set of given strings.

```
select *
from tbl_contacts
where title in ('General Manager', 'Owner', 'President')
order by field(title, 'General Manager', 'Owner', 'President')
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What if one of the entries in column title is NULL and I want all NULL records to appear at the end of selected list? I tried to use order by field but no matter what I do, NULL are coming first. :-(

Answer (score 3):

Set your own order:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts 
WHERE title IN ('General Manager', 'Owner', 'President')
ORDER BY CASE
              WHEN title = 'Owner' THEN 0
              WHEN title = 'President' THEN 1
              WHEN title = 'General Manager' THEN 2
          END
```

Comment: This helps in my case when we have an unknown value : `ELSE 4`